# Ancestors missing from ThruLines?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

At AncestryDNA, until a few days or so ago, all my expected direct ancestors were listed correctly by ThruLines.  Now when I look at them some of them have gone missing.  For example, today I can only see 12 out of my 16 2nd great grandparents there.

What is causing this, and how do I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what is causing this but I strongly suspect that it relates to another oddity that I have noticed in my tree.  That oddity is that many of the relationships seem to have recently flipped from Biological to Unknown, or from Spouse to Unknown, and I am noticing such flipped relationships on every direct ancestor of mine who has disappeared from ThruLines (on Ancestry.com.au) that I have investigated so far.

For example when I go to the profile of my 2nd great grandfather John Murch Stacy, who is missing from ThruLines, and choose **Edit > Edit Relationships** what I see is below, with red arrows where relationships seem to have flipped, with one of them being to my great grandfather Clement Howard Stacy.

[image]

As I find these I fix them, and after a day or two at least two of my missing direct ancestors have reappeared on ThruLines.

I have reported this to Ancestrysupport@ancestry.com.au who responded:

> Thank you for contacting Ancestry regarding problems with your
>   ThruLines not generating properly. We are always sorry to learn our
>   members had a frustrating experience but are happy to help.
>
> Thank you for reporting this concern. We are currently investigating
>   this issue. If this is found to be a bug/issue, please note that we
>   cannot provide any sort of time frame as to when it will be resolved.
>   We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I found a way to find these problems systematically in the GEDCOM file.  See [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/finding-unknown-relationships-in-ancestry-family-trees/18199#18199)