# Finding Unknown relationships in Ancestry family trees

Tags: ancestry.com, family-tree-maker

In my Ancestry.com.au family tree there are an unknown number of Unknown relationships that should be Biological relationships.

I often spot them when I am on a profile page like below:

[image]

These are errors and I do not know how they were introduced into my tree.  They are easily fixed using the Edit > Edit Relationships button to turn them to Biological but they mess up other Ancestry functionality like ThruLines.

Is there any way to search for Unknown relationships in an Ancestry tree?

I am hoping for an Ancestry.com solution, but I also have Family Tree Maker 2017.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same question today, and figured out an answer.  It involves the raw GEDCOM file, but it is possible.

- Step 1: Export your raw GEDCOM file from Ancestry.

  - Tree Settings
  - Tree Info Page
  - Manage your Tree section
  - Export Tree
  - (When ready) download
- Step 2: Open the GEDCOM in a text editor like Notepad++
- Step 3: Search for "REL UNKNOWN".  Here is an example from my GEDCOM:

  - The text below stands for Family 15 with with husband 56 and wife 75 has a Child 77 who has a natural relationship with the Father and an unknown Relationship with the mother

```
0 @F15@ FAM 
1 HUSB @P56@
1 WIFE @P75@
1 CHIL @P77@
2 _FREL Natural
2 _MREL Unknown
```

- Step 4:  Search for the child: @P77@

  - You will find multiple places where @P77@ exists, but you are looking for the individual record.

```
0 @P77@ INDI
```

- Step 5:  Scroll down from the individual record until you find their name

```
1 NAME John John Johnson
```

- Step 6:  Go back to this person in Ancestry.com and fix the relationship

Answer (score -4):

just get family tree maker, sync your tree from ancestry, relationship report, go through the unknowns and sync back to ancestry - really easy

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please look at the [help] to learn more about the site.  One-line answers with minimal information aren't a good fit for our site. Your answer could be improved by recognizing that the OP has Family Tree Maker 2017, which no longer syncs with Ancestry.